# Access .pem file which has been automatically generated by the Chrome Webstore

Tags: google-chrome-extension, pem, chrome-web-store

I have the following problem: my Google Chrome extension has been submitted *before* the packaging mechanism (i.e. ship your own pem file to the webstore) was introduced. 
Now I'd like to update the extension but since I don't have a pem file the webstore will automatically generate a new one, hence, my extension will have a new ID which causes the update mechanism to fail and I'd loose my existing user base.

Is it possible to get a pem file for the old extension or can I provide my own pem file w/o breaking the update mechansim.

Thanks, 
 Peter

Answer (score 1):

If your extension is already in the Chrome Web Store, then you don't need to have a .pem file to submit an update. If your extension is not in the Web Store, but you'd like to move it there and keep the same ID, then you can upload your old .pem file with the name `key.pem` (see [the documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/packaging.html#upload) for details).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an ideal solution but you can call it Plan B. The updated extension (with a new id) can automatically disable the old one, by looking for the old one's id.

```
chrome.management.getAll(function(ext){
    if(ext.length===1) return;

    for(var i=0; i<ext.length; i++){
        if(ext[i].id!=="ENTER_OLD_EXTENSION_ID_HERE") continue;
        chrome.management.setEnabled(ext[i].id,false);
    }
});
```